# How to set doctype in GWT

Tags: gwt, doctype

I cannot find the way how to force GWT to use a specific doctype in the header of the compiled HTML page.

I am not using UI binder and the UI elements in my application are added using `RootPanel.get.add()` in the `onModuleLoad()` method of the entry point class.

Comment: What is a "compiled HTML page" from the GWT point of view?

Comment: @Andrei By that I mean on the resulting HTML page in the web browser.

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I should be clearer: talking about the HTML page that hosts your GWT application, or do you use GWT to generate a HTML page other than the hosting page?

Comment: I use GWT that generates an HTML page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DOCTYPE of your GWT application is set inside the host page.

Inside the GWT documentation you'll find this:

> The GWT 2.0 layout system is intended to work only in “standards
>   mode”. This means that you should always place the following
>   declaration at the top of your HTML pages: <!DOCTYPE html>

link: [GWT documentation](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiPanels.html)

So, you should use "standards mode" in your application.

Comment: I am not using the host page. Should that page be located on the server side? In fact in the application the server side is a completely different technology, so the GWT is used only on the client part and the communication with the server is organized using RESTful services.

Comment: You have to add your xxx.nocache.js. Where do you do that?

Comment: GWT app does not exist without a host page. It does not matter how your app communicates with the server. Somewhere there is an HTML page ("host page") which is delivered when a user calls your app, as well as related CSS and JS files, including compiled GWT code. GWT code executes only when a browser loads and renders this HTML page.

Comment: @AndreiVolgin You are right. There is a host page. The reason I could not find it because my project is completely separated from the server side, wich is managed by another team. Thank you for pointing it out.